# How to get a property of a changed input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several inputs on which I want to handle the change event using `.on("change")`. I've put the inputs in an array of variables like that:

```
$(document).on("change keyup", [
    input1,
    input2,
    input3
], function() {
    // doing stuff
});
```

Each variable has a jQuery selector assigned to it like this:

```
var input1 = $("input[name=input1]");
var input2 = $("input[name=input2]");
var input3 = $("input[name=input3]");
```

Each input has a data attribute which I want to get from `this` context when the input is changed. For example if input1 has been changed, I want to get its data attribute the following way:

```
this.data("someAttribute")
```

But I'm afraid that `this` doesn't work with selectors from `.on()` function but with the initial `$(document)` selector and I'm actually trying to get the data attribute from `document` instead of the input that has been changed which is not what I need.

**Note:** With what I'm trying to do, selecting multiple inputs like this `$(input1, input2, input3)` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: The second attribute must be a string selector, not an array of objects: http://api.jquery.com/on/ I'd suggest putting a common class on all the `input` elements and selecting by that instead of the `name` attribute

Comment: What does the markup of the inputs look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than group the inputs that need binding into an array and passing the array to the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (which isn't allowed anyway), you should give the `input` elements in question a common CSS class and then write your event binding like this:

```
$(document).on("change keyup", ".theClass", function() {
    // doing stuff
});
```

Then, within the event handler, you'll need to pass `this` to the JQuery function like this: `$(this).data()` because [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is a JQuery method and won't be available on the native DOM element that `this` alone refers to.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".input", function() {
    console.log($(this).data("test"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='input1' class="input" data-test='one'>
<input type='text' name='input2' class="input" data-test='two'>
<input type='text' name='input3' class="input" data-test='three'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your inputs a CSS class

```js
$('.change').on('change keyup', function() {
       console.log($(this).val());
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="change">
<input type="text" class="change">
<input type="text" class="change">
```